# Opening Word documents from IE LAG Windows 7 IE8

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, internet-explorer-8, iis-7

I'm having a lot of trouble opening documents from a network share in word using IE.

The documents are located in a network share which is mapped to a virtual directory. The documents are accessed by URLs that link to the virtual directory.

There is now a huge lag (sometimes up to a minute or two!) from when clicking on the link to the document opening in word. The 'loading disc' in IE just keeps spinning and nothing happens. Sometimes a pop up box appears with 'opening file - (address)' but it still takes ages.

I've tried setting in the registry to open the files directly in ie but to no avail.

Anyone have any ideas?

Steve

Comment: Any ideas at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for information, this problem was resolved by disabling IPv6 on the client PC.  Don't ask me why but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like the network is slow. Depending on the documents. I know there is the same lag when I open a document on Windows Live, but it is only like 2 seconds.

Comment: Kind of right, see below